# C# XML Merging (2+ files)

Tags: c#, xml

I am having problem to merge 2 or more xml files into 1 using c#.

I am doing it with DataSets:

```
//ds1,ds2,ds3 are DataSets
private void MyMethod()
{
    ds1.ReadXml(tmpStream);
    ds2.ReadXml(tmpStream);    
    ds1.Merge(ds2);
}
```

but i dont want to use DataSet. i am searching for another way.

**first XML is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
  <item>
    <path>'filePath'</path>
    <deleted>0</deleted>
    <date>9/23/2010 11:30:03 AM</date>
  </item> 
</catalog>
```

**the second is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
  <item>
    <path>'filePath'</path>
    <deleted>0</deleted>
    <date>9/23/2010 11:30:03 AM</date>
  </item> 
</catalog>
```

result must be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <catalog>
      <item>
        <path>'filePath'</path>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <date>9/23/2010 11:30:03 AM</date>
      </item> 
      <item>
        <path>'filePath'</path>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <date>9/23/2010 11:30:03 AM</date>
      </item> 
    </catalog>
```

Comment: You need to give more details of the kind of merging you want to do. What's the structure of the XML files? Do they share the same root element? Do you just want all the elements in both files, or should some elements be merged?

Comment: Both xmls are same, what do you want to merge? You want to merge it into one? Or you want to have two nodes of `<items>` after merging? What should be the output after merge?

Comment: it would help a lot if you showed us what you would want the result to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though this isn't really clear of what sort of merge you want, this article [`Merging XML Files, Schema Validation, and More`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164169.aspx) might help you get the idea.

Easiest could be, if you dont want any checks to be performed(duplicates, zombies, etc)

```
var ResultXml = XDocument.Load("file1.xml");
ResultXml.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("file2.xml").Root.Elements());
```

Answer (score 3):

To merge XML files into resulting one, you could use Microsoft's [XML Diff and Patch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3471df57-0c08-46b4-894d-f569aa7f7892&DisplayLang=en) C# API. You could read more about it in [Eric White's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/) post: "[OpenXmlDiff.Exe: A Utility to Find the Differences Between Two Open XML Documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/06/14/openxmldiff-exe-a-utility-to-find-the-differences-between-two-open-xml-documents.aspx)"